# Power series convergence (center of the power series)

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

Does every power series converge at at least one point? Would this point be the point at which the power series is centered. Also, is there a proof for the above question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you plug in $x=a$ in your series
$$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty c_n(x-a)^n
$$
you get a finite value, namely $c_0$.

Comment: What if the the power series is  ∑n=0∞cn(x−a)^-n. Hence, if x = a, then the power series would be undefined and infinite? Or is my thinking wrong

Comment: In that case, it wouldn't be defined for $x=a$.

Comment: So the statement that a power series is always convergent at least one point is wrong? Or might there be another value for x which causes the power series to be convergent?

Comment: Usually, a power series is defined to have non-negative powers only. If it has negative integer powers, it is called a Laurent series.